# Is there any rule of thumb to determine the amount of data needed to train a CNN

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, training, datasets, data-augmentation

I am training an AlexNet Convolutional Neural Network to classify images in a dataset. I want to know if there is any general rule for using data augmentation in training a neural network. How can I make sure about the amount of data, and how can I know if I need more data?

Comment: It's not very clear the question in the title though. What do you mean "rule for number of applying"? Maybe your question is: "Is there any rule of thumb to determine the amount of data needed to train a CNN? Moreover, it seems that you're asking another question: "Which data augmentation techiniques should you use? Is there any rule?". Please, if you have two question, ask each of them in its separate post.

Comment: @nbro No, I just want to know about the amount of data, I edited the title again, sorry for my english.

Comment: So, why did you write "I want to know if there is any general rule for using data augmentation in training a neural network"?

Comment: Your question seems quite broad and unclear – especially the added question about data augmentation. My understanding is that there is no "rule of thumb"; the amount of data you need depends on the complexity of the images that you are / will be dealing with. Here are some sources on data augmentation: https://journalofbigdata.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40537-019-0197-0 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04621 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08764